# Springer template doesn't read bib file properly

Tags: bibtex

I have downloaded Springer SIVP template package from its website and uploaded to Overleaf. In the template, it says I can use one of the `spbasic`, `spmpsci`, or `spphys` styles for BibTeX. The template only includes the `spphys.bst` file.

When I test the allowed styles, `spbasic` and `spmpsci` both don't call my `ref.bib` file. Therefore, no Reference section shows up on the PDF preview. `spphys` style calls the bib file however this time it skips and doesn't show article titles in the Reference section. It shows authors and other fields properly. I got stuck here and need your help. What is the problem here? (My `ref.bib` file includes all required fields properly.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is there any error/warning showed in the Overleaf log section when typesetting the document as PDF related to bibliographies?

Comment: I've resolved the problem, I started to write my own bst file until fortunately I was able to find the missing .bst files from another link of Springer. The spphys style is designed not to show the titles so no surprise here anymore.  Thanks for the help.